# RuntimeError: cutlassF: no kernel found to launch! when running huggingface transformer on colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to run this notebook on Colab:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rt318Ew-5dDw21YZx2zK2vnxbsuDAchH?usp=sharing

And getting an error:

```
RuntimeError: cutlassF: no kernel found to launch!
```

The error occurs at the 4th step:

```
outputs = pipe(
    prompt,
    max_new_tokens=256,
    do_sample=True,
    temperature=0.1,
    top_p=0.95
)
print(outputs[0]["generated_text"])
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
torch.backends.cuda.enable_mem_efficient_sdp(False)
torch.backends.cuda.enable_flash_sdp(False)
```

it work with me.